# QtCreator: Header files not found when using CMake

Tags: qt, cmake, qt-creator, qmake

I have tried this on multiple platforms, experiencing the same issue every time.

I successfully build and run my C++ OpenFrameworks application using QtCreator - no problems are encountered.

Then, I successfully use qmake to generate the project file.

Yet when I attempt to make the executable, I receive the following error:

```
make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -c -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -std=gnu++1z  -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=12 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -I/opt/homebrew/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/opt/homebrew/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I/opt/homebrew/share/qt/mkspecs/macx-clang -F/opt/homebrew/lib -o main.o src/main.cpp
src/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'ofMain.h' file not found
#include "ofMain.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I can go into the .pro file and add things to the include path manually, but I don't see why these includes aren't generated automatically?

Comment: Can you post your CMakeLists.txt file? You do realize that a change to your .pro file doesn't affect cmake, right?

Comment: I do not get it. Are you using cmake or qmake?

Comment: qmake to generate the .pro file and cmake to make the .pro an executable

Comment: I don't seem to have a CMakeLists.txt in the working directory

Comment: correction, sorry! I'm using qmake not cmake

Answer (score 0):

I think I recognized your problem.
The file name is `main.cpp` in the `src/` folder. Based on its location in the `src/` folder, I think your `ofMain.h` file is also in the `src/` folder. Now a question: did you add `src/` to your include path? If not with the following line:

```
INCLUDEPATH += \
    src/
```

It should work now I hope.
Have a nice day!